# Javascript Knob/Slider Control

Tags: javascript, slider, jquery-knob

I have found an example of a map that uses a knob/slider to control the opacity on a map. I would like to use this same knob/slider but for something different and not part of a map. I have the code (http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-overlay-opacity-control/) but I'm not sure what I would need to extract to simply keep the knob and be able to use it on a webpage to display (for example) a number between 1 and 1000.

Help appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Why not just use the jQueryUI slider?

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing... I will check it out. I've seen something circular but I'm looking for something more horizontal. edit: exactly what I'm looking for, thank you so much

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps jQueryUI's slider would work for you. You can see an example [here](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#default) and read documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend a knobs control component I've created to manipulate different aspects on a web page:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yaireo/knobs

I've first made it for my own needs and then release as an open-source for others to enjoy as well